# AngularJS: How to ignore null values while filtering?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to filter `instructor_name` but this table has many null values, how should I ignore those null fields and search/filter only  from fileds which are not null

```
 filter:

 `item.instructor_name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.courses_search.toLowerCase()) != -1`
```

and because, there are many fields which are null Im getting an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'instructor_name' of null

```
$scope.livesearch = function(item) {
    if ($scope.courses_search == undefined) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (item.subject_cd.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.courses_search.toLowerCase()) != -1 ||

            item.acad_group.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.courses_search.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}

$scope.filterFunc = function() {
    return function(item) {

        if (item !== null && typeof item.class_instructor_name !== 'undefined') {
            return item.class_instructor_name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.courses_search.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        }
        return false;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing item to null, but if item is undefined, the next validation will take place because (undefined !== null), so it will try to look up instructor_name on undefined, which obviously will not work.

AngularJS has it's own checkers, angular.isDefined() and angular.isUndefined(). You can use one of those, or do a slightly different check, such as:

```
if (item && item.instructor_name) ...
```

If you're using lodash, you can simply do:
    if (_.get(item, 'instructor_name')) ...

Answer (score -1):

One option is to add the filter on the controller and handle null checks from there.
Remeber to check if the value is defined before appling the toLowerCase() method.

```
$scope.filterFunc = function() {
  return function(item) {
    if (typeof $scope.courses_search !== 'undefined' && item !== null) {
        if(typeof item.subject_cd !== 'undefined'){
            return item.subject_cd.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.courses_search.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        }
        if(typeof item.acad_group !== 'undefined'){
            return item.acad_group.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.courses_search.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
  };
};
```

Then in view

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterFunc"
```

Comment: if I do that I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Comment: getting same error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Comment: Your answer does not helped its still showing error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Comment: @JKLM updated the answer. note that if you add more values that you want to flter on you need to check if the value is define before appling the toLowerCase()